# Mockito object methods of another class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

Hi I request your help to know how to emulate the method of the class `Validator.validateConnection();`. 
The problem is that the method `validateConnection` not exist in the class `Class_Implementation` and I don't want to create that method in the class `Class_Implementation`. The method `validateConnection` do a connection to the database to know if the connection is alive. When Mockito runs I get a `java.Lang.NullPointerException` that is caused by `NamingException` - need to specify class name in environment.

The real problem is when I call in Mockito test the line:

```
Boolean resp = mockImpl.checkConnection();
```

..in the `checkConnection()` the class `Validator.validateConnection();` is trying to connect to database. I just want emulate this line and return `true` or `false`, but the problem is that the method `validateConnection()` is an instance of class `Validator`.

If need more information for fix this please let me know.

```
public class Class_Implementation {

    public boolean  checkConnection() {
        boolean isConnectionAlive = false;

        Validator.validateConnection();

        // another things for do

        return false;
    }

}

public class Validator {

    public static Boolean validateConnection() {
        Connection conn = new Connection();

        Boolean connectionAlive = false;
        connectionAlive = conn.isConnectionAlive();

        if (connectionAlive) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}

public class Connection {

    public boolean isConnectionAlive() {
        // Code for connection to DB
    }

}

// class for do the test
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Class_Implementation.class,Validator.class}) 
public class TestConnection {

    @Test
    public void validate_Connection() throws Exception {
        Class_Implementation mockImpl = PowerMock.createPartialMock(Class_Implementation.class);

        PowerMock.mockStatic(Validator.class);

        PowerMockito.when(mockImpl,  Validator.validateConnection() ).thenReturn(true);

        PowerMock.replayAll(mockImpl);

        Boolean resp = mockImpl.checkConnection();

        PowerMock.verifyAll();

        Validate.notNull(resp);
    }

}
```

Comment: Wait, you create a _new connection_ each time?

Comment: yes alway that the line Validator.validateConnection(); is executed, the class do the connection. But i do this example for not lost the focus on how mock the like Validator.validateConnection(); and return only tru or false without create one mothod in the class Class_Implementation

Answer (score 1):

Use a Validator object instead of its static methods and inject the Validator into Class_Implementation (by constructor). This is called [Dependency Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html). In your test you can inject a mock of the Validator.

```
public class Validator {
  public boolean validateConnection() {
    ...
  }
}

public class Class_Implementation {
  private final Validator validator;

  public Class_Implementation(Validator validator) {
    this.validator = validator;
  }

  public boolean checkConnection() {
    ...
    validator.validateConnection();
    ...
  }
}

public public class Class_ImplementationTest {

  @Test
  public void validate_Connection() throws Exception {
    Validator validator = Mockito.mock(Validator.class);
    Mockito.when(validator.validateConnection()).thenReturn(true);

    Class_Implementation impl = new Class_Implementation(validator);
    boolean response = mockImpl.checkConnection();

    Assert.assertTrue(response);
  }
}
```

I made some additional changes to your code.

1. Don't return a Boolean object if there are only two states.
2. A Unit test tests on class and is named like the class with an additional Test prefix.
3. You don't need PowerMock if you have nice code.

Answer (score 0):

Just mock your `Class_Implementation` (you should change the name and stick to Java naming standards by the way) and stub the `validateConnection()` method:

```
final Class_Implementation mock = mock(Class_Implementation.class);

when(mock.checkConnection()).thenReturn(true); // or false
```

But anyway, what you should mock is the interface to start with.

Comment: Thanks for the response fge,  the problem here is i can't mock the entire class Class_Implementation because after execute the line : Validator.validateConnection(); the methos do another things...

Comment: You should reconsider your design; for instance, make your Validator an interface and pass it as a parameter to your class implementation or something. But as it seems to be written, your code is very hard to test. It looks like you need to look for PowerMockito here, since mockito cannot mock static methods. But first, consider a redesign, it will save time in the long run.